# Fail2ban no matches for nginx-botsearch

Tags: regex, nginx, fail2ban

I try to use the filter nginx-botsearch.conf in fail2ban.

This is the entry to be checked:

> [error] 4904#4904: *2057 "/var/www/html/XXXX" is not found (2: No
>   such file or directory), client: XX.XXX.XXX.XX, server: XXXXX.XX,
>   request: "GET /_asterisk/ HTTP/1.1", host: "XX.XX.XXX.XX"

With this failregex:

```
[INCLUDES]

# Load regexes for filtering
before = botsearch-common.conf

[Definition]

failregex = ^<HOST> \- \S+ \[\] \"(GET|POST|HEAD) \/<block> \S+\" 404 .+$
            ^ \[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ (\S+ )?\"\S+\" (failed|is not found) \(2\: No such file or directory\), client\: <HOST>\, server\: \S*\, request: \"(GET|POST|HEAD) \/<block> \S+\"\, .*?$

ignoreregex =
```

But if i test it, it doesn't find any matches. I can't find the issue here.

## Running tests

```
sudo fail2ban-regex --print-all-missed /var/log/nginx/error.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-botsearch.conf
```

## Results

```
Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [2] Year(?P<_sep>[-/.])Month(?P=_sep)Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:,Microseconds)?
`-

Lines: 2 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 2 missed
[processed in 0.00 sec]

|- Missed line(s):
|  2018/04/06 10:37:18 [error] 1193#1193: *2045 open() "/var/www/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: XXXX, server: XXXX, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", host: "XXXX"
|  2018/04/06 10:37:18 [error] 1193#1193: *2045 open() "/var/www/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: XXXX, server: XXXX, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", host: "XXXX"
```

Comment: Check if it misses your entry with: `sudo fail2ban-regex --print-all-missed /var/log/nginx/error.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-botsearch.conf` If it does miss it, then you'll need to add custom regex to catch it.

Comment: No other result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so standard regex does not catch required lines in your log.

Copy `ngnix-botsearch.conf` to `ngnix-botsearch.local` :

```
sudo cp /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/ngnix-botsearch.conf /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/ngnix-botsearch.local
```

Open `ngnix-botsearch.local` with your favorite editor and in `[Definition]` section replace `failregex =` piece with:

```
failregex = ^ \[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ (\S+ )?\"\S+\" (failed|is not found) \(2\: No such file or directory\), client\: <HOST>, server\: \S*\, request: \"(GET|POST|HEAD) \/favicon\.ico \S+\"\, host: \"\S*\".*?
```

This will add file with custom regex, which shall catch your missed lines. Save the file and then do:

```
sudo fail2ban-client reload
```

Now check filters again:

```
sudo fail2ban-regex --print-all-missed /var/log/nginx/error.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-botsearch.conf
```

You can check/create regular expressions to catch missing lines in logs here: https://regex101.com For instance, here is the regex for your missing lines: https://regex101.com/r/QGxC0k/1, but be aware that Regex101 does **not** understand `<HOST>` and other aliases from fail2ban! You need to replace them with appropriate regex.

And check regularly your settings for the lines that fail2ban misses in your logs.

Hope this will help.